# Get radiobox checked value by name in java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing an application in that there is need that I want checked value by name in java script or jquery.
My HTML code is

```
 <input type="radio" name="type1" value="Manual"  /> Manual<br/>
 <input type="radio" name="type1" value="Auto"  /> Auto
```

and my javascript code is

```
var aqi_type = (document.getElementsByName('type'+id).value)
alert(aqi_type);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUZwS.png

When I check the radio box I am getting value as undefined.

Advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="type1"]:checked').val()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GBtX4/)

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="type1"]').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert($(this).val())
})
```

[DEMO With change event](http://jsfiddle.net/b33pR/)

### EDIT

As per comment you can use

```
var ids = 1;
$('input[type="radio"][name="type' + ids + '"]:checked').val()
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but in my code name is not fixed.             <input type="radio" name="type'+idss+'" value="Manual" /> Manual<br/><input type="radio" name="type'+idss+'" value="Auto" /> Auto. I have to pass name="type'+idss+'" this value

Comment: @RahulNarhe, I have updated answer. If want to use change event, ping me again

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input[name="type1"]').prop('checked',true)){
  alert($(this).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="type1" value="Manual" id="radio1"  /> Manual<br/>
```

Try,

```
if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
  aqi_type = document.getElementById('radio1').value;
}
```

This works in IE8 and above and all other browsers,

```
document.querySelector('input[name="type1"]:checked').value;
```

**JQuery Style:**

```
$('input[name="type1"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getElementsByName you can use class attribute like class="type1". So the html would be:

```
<input type="radio" class="type1" value="Manual"  /> Manual<br/>
<input type="radio" class="type1" value="Auto"  /> Auto
```

And the jquery:

```
var values = '';
for(var i = 0; i < $('.type1').length; i++){
   values += $('.type1').eq(i).val() + '|';
}
alert(values);
```

Please try this!

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all radio buttons irrespective of name.

```
 $("input:radio").change("click", function () {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            alert($(this).val())
    })
```

or

You can use below lines which will get all radio buttons starting with type:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name*="type"]').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        alert($(this).val())
})
```